# Different translations of "yᵊhōvâ 'ĕlōhîm yᵊhōvâ 'eḥāḏ"

Tags: hebrew, deuteronomy

In Deuteronomy 6:4 (KJV)

> (...) The LORD our God is one LORD

According to the [Blueletterbible](https://www.blueletterbible.org/kjv/deu/6/1/t_conc_159004) this part comes from

> yᵊhōvâ 'ĕlōhîm yᵊhōvâ 'eḥāḏ

Check other bible versions. In general, there's agreement that "yᵊhōvâ 'ĕlōhîm" means "the Lord our God". Yet, overall they have a different translations (found at least three).

What's the reason behind that?

Comment: YHVD = Ehud. Two ways to spell the same name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Deuteronomy | **Devarim 6:4**, we read and sing!

> יְהֹוָ֥ה אֱלֹהֵ֖ינוּ יְהֹוָ֥ה אֶחָֽד

- Although transliterated : **"YeHoVaH Elohei-nu YeHoVaH Echad"** in Hebrew.
- The Shema is sung "[Adonai] Eloheinu, [Adonai] Echad" in reverence to HaShem.
- YHVH יְהֹוָ֥ה is given the titles : HaShem (The-Name) or **אֲדֹנָי Adonai (Lord)** in order for Yehudim to not pronounce The Name of God.
- This tradition of saying or singing **אֲדֹנָי Adonai (Lord)** instead of The Name **יְהֹוָ֥ה YHVH** is associated with the observance of Exodus / **Shemot 20:7** stating לֹ֥א תִשָּׂ֛א אֶת־שֵֽׁם־יְהֹוָ֥ה אֱלֹהֶ֖יךָ לַשָּׁ֑וְא כִּ֣י לֹ֤א יְנַקֶּה֙ יְהֹוָ֔ה אֵ֛ת אֲשֶׁר־יִשָּׂ֥א אֶת־שְׁמ֖וֹ לַשָּֽׁוְא You shall not take the name of YHVH your God in vain, for YHVH will not hold blameless anyone who takes His name in vain.

In English, Deuteronomy 6:4 would read : **"YHVH [is] our God. YHVH [is] One."** In reverence to The-Name, English bibles state : **"The LORD our God, The LORD is one."**

**Deuteronomy 6:4** [NASB]

> The Lord is our God, the Lord is one!

**Deuteronomy 6:4 [NIV]**

> The Lord our God, the Lord is one

- We see the Shema proclaimed by Yeshua of Nazareth as The Greatest Commandment in **Mark 12:29**.

**Mark 12:29** [ESV]

> The Lord our God, the Lord is one.

**Mark 12:29** [NASB]

> The Lord our God, The Lord is one.

**The Shema is a proclamation of faith in our God יְהֹוָ֥ה YHVH.**

Answer (score 1):

I do not see a problem here.  Note the snip from https://biblehub.com/interlinear/deuteronomy/6-4.htm

[image]

Most versions render this rather literally as (typically)

- Hear, O Israel: The LORD our God, the LORD is one.

Answer (score 0):

God's name cannot contain the definite article ["the"]. In the Greek Scriptures [NT and LXX 6:4] there are no definite articles [the] for the words "Kyrios".

Comment: @ Biblia - Thank you for your interest in Hebrew research. However to be productive it would be better "to flesh out" your research, with references and  resultant translation with their justification. Keep studying the Bible, it's great for the soul.